# In scala expected Array[String] got Array[Nothing] - how to deal with it?

Tags: scala

In the following code, how to deal with the function returning "nothing" error.
Use case:

- commands arguments are passed into args: Array[String]
- using the below condition statement:

  - if args is blank, and do something
  - else if args has some value, i will simply return back args

Issue:
the code throws a compile time error stating that

- expected: Array[string]
- and got: Array[Noting]

How to deal with this in scala? Using options, if yes then how?

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  inp_schemas = Array("a","b")
  inp_schemas.map{ x_schema =>                                                                 
    val tables: Array[String] = 
      if (args.length == 0) {
        <do something that returns array[string]>                                
      } else {
        args
      } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you returning in `<do something>`?

Comment: do something works well. it does return the array[string]. the issue arises in the else statement when no input args are given by the user

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider here.

1) The return value of the `<do something>` block. Make sure it is `Array[String]`.

2) The main thing is however that your `map` function returns `Unit`. The last statement is an assignment to `tables`. To fix this either remove the variable and the assignment or add what you want return at the end of the `map` function. For the second solution, see below code.

```
inp_schemas.map{ x_schema =>                                                                 
  val tables: Array[String] = 
    if (args.length == 0) {
      <do something> // make sure this part returns an Array[String]                           
    } else {
      args
    }
  tables // returns tables
}
```

Comment: the issue is with the else statement - when there is no input argument, args is "null"/nothing and thats where my val tables throws a type mismatch

Comment: @datmannz The above should work for both when `args` is empty and when it's not (as long as the `<do something>` return is correct).

Comment: "The main thing is however that your map function returns Unit" I agree on your comment. I have changed "map" to "foreach"

Comment: @datmannz There is no problem to use `map` as long as you have a return at the last line.

Comment: I realized that I don't need to use map. I am actually not doing any transformation to the values in the inp_schemas array. So foreach makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

When your `args: Array[String]` contains nothing, i.e. `val args = Array()` it will throw that error, since it is expecting Array[String] but args will be Array[Nothing]. You would have to check your commandline input and `<do something>` should return an Array[String].

Answer (score 0):

So the trick was on how I was defining args in the main class.

Earlier this was what was happening:

```
With no cmd input> val args = Array()
Results in> args: Array[Nothing] = Array()

With cmd inp> val args = Array("a","b")
Results in> args: Array[String] = Array(a, b)
```

I then explicitly defined args as Array[String]:

```
With no cmd input> val args:Array[String] = Array()
Results in> Array[String] = Array() 
With cmd inp> val args:Array[String] = Array("a","b")
Results in> Array[String] = Array(a, b)
```

That is Array[String] in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Inst your map function returning Unit regardless whatever you do inside if clause  and the parameter you pass. The return type of function is Array[Unit] and the value is Array((), ())

I am guessing this is what you wanted to do?

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  val inp_schemas = Array("a","b")
  inp_schemas.map{ x_schema =>
    val tables: Array[String] =
      if (args.length == 0) {
        Array("a")
      } else {
        args
      }
    tables // Return tables
  }
}
```